# Spring Mvc Web Application with Rest interface

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-applications, spring-mvc

in my exercise i have to develop a spring application which should be accessible through a WebGUI AND a REST service. 
Now i browed through the examples of Spring MVC, there is [this](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-3-mvc-hello-world-example/) hello world tutorial on Spring MVC.

The controller looks like as follows:

```
 @Controller
 @RequestMapping("/welcome")
 public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
    return "hello";
    }
}
```

Then i looked through the [Spring REST example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-3-rest-hello-world-example/) which looks like this:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/movie")
public class MovieController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getMovie(@PathVariable String name, ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("movie", name);
    return "list";

}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getDefaultMovie(ModelMap model) {

    model.addAttribute("movie", "this is default movie");
    return "list";

}

}
```

Now I am wondering, how do these two examples (Spring-mvc and Spring-rest) differ?
They both use the same annotations and work similar. Aren't that both just REST examples?

How can I provide a Rest-Interface to a Spring-MVC application?

regards

Comment: A service being RESTful has to do with how resources are accessed.  See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_APIs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both samples are about Spring Web MVC.

You should pay more attention to definitions, like what is REST

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

> Representational State Transfer is intended to evoke an image of how a
>   well-designed Web application behaves: presented with a network of Web
>   pages (a virtual state-machine), the user progresses through an
>   application by selecting links (state transitions), resulting in the
>   next page (representing the next state of the application) being
>   transferred to the user and rendered for their use.

Spring Web MVC greatly facilitates developing REST web APIs and that's it.

Answer (score 2):

In order to provide rest interface to Spring MVC application, you can apply @RequestMapping annotation with a path name to each of the methods in controller, this creates a unique URL path for each of the rest services you would like to provide.

Meaning, the rest services are nothing but the methods in Spring MVC controller with @RequestMapping annotation.

If you would like to learn how Spring MVC supports Rest Based services, the below link might help:

http://blog.springsource.org/2009/03/08/rest-in-spring-3-mvc/#features

Answer (score -1):

Rememeber @ResponseBody as return type on method is going to be REST.
ofcourse returned object can be negotiated with either JSON or XML.